# Making a Python executable for a specific task

Tags: python, json, api, widget, executable

I'm a neuroscientist and thus not very Python skilled, but i have managed to come up with a code which uses API access to download certain neurons from a specific website (neuromorpho.org). I want this to be publicly available so that other people which are not that familiar with Python can easily get what they need (planing on posting it to GitHub and making other similar stuff like this).

So i wanted to basically create an executable file in which people can select what they want and get a .csv file with neurons at the end. This perfectly works from inside the JupyterNotebook. However, when i use Auto Py to EXE to create and executable it doesn't work. It works for a long time, creates thousands of files (more than 1GB of data) and when you launch the executable nothing happens.

I presume it has something to do with the ipywidget that i have used to create selections for the initial query.

Here is the first part of the code where i try to query the neurons based on the widget selection:

```
    widg1 = widget.Dropdown(options=['abdominal ganglion', 'accessory lobe', 'accessory olfactory bulb', 'adult subesophageal zone', 'amygdala'
                                    'antenna', 'antennal lobe', 'anterior olfactory nucleus', 'basal forbrain', 'basal ganglia',
                                    'brainstem', 'Central complex', 'Central nervous system', 'cerebellum', 'cerebral ganglion',
                                    'Cochlea', 'corpus callosum', 'cortex', 'electrosensory lobe', 'endocrine system', 'enthorinal cortex',
                                    'eye circuit', 'forebrain', 'fornix', 'ganglion', 'hippocampus', 'hypothalamus', 'lateral complex',
                                    'lateral horn', 'lateral line organ', 'left', 'Left Adult Central Complex', 'Left Mushroom Body', 'main olfactory bulb'
                                    'meninges', 'mesencephalon', 'myelencephalon', 'neocortex', 'nuchal organs', 'olfactory cortex', 'olfactory pit', 'optic lobe',
                                    'pallium', 'parasubiculum', ' peptidergic circuit', 'peripheral nervous system', 'pharyngeal nervous system', 'pons', 'Pro-subiculum', 
                                    'protocerebrum', 'retina', 'retinorecipient mesencephalon and diencephalon', 'Right Adult Central Complex',
                                    'Right Mushroom Body', 'somatic nervous system', 'spinal cord', 'stomatogastric ganglion', 'subesophageal ganglion',
                                    'subesophageal zone-(SEZ)', 'subiculum', 'subpallium', 'Subventricular zone', 'thalamus', 'ventral nerve cord',
                                    'ventral striatum', 'ventral thalamus', 'ventrolateral neuropils', 'Not reported'], 
                            value=  'cerebellum', description='Brain Region:')
    display(widg1)
    
    widg2 = widget.Dropdown(options=['African wild dog', 'agouti', 'Apis mellifera', 'Aplysia', 'Axolotl', 'Baboon',
                                    'Blind mole-rat', 'blowfly', 'Blue wildebeest', 'Bonobo', 'bottlenose dolphin', 'C. elegans',
                                    'Calango lizard', 'capuchin monkey', 'Caracal', 'cat', 'cheetah', 'chicken', 'chimpanzee', 'Clam worm', 'clouded leopard', 'Crab', 'cricket',
                                    'Crisia eburnea', 'Domestic dog', 'domestic pig', 'dragonfly', 'drosophila melanogaster', 'drosophila sechellia',
                                    'elephant', 'ferret', 'giraffe', 'goldfish', 'grasshopper', 'Greater kudu', 'guinea pig', 'Hamster', 'human', 'humpback whale', 
                                    'Lemur', 'leopard', 'Lion', 'locust', 'manatee', 'minke whale', 'Mongoose', 'monkey', 'Mormyrid fish', 'moth',
                                     'mouse', 'pouched lamprey', 'Praying mantis (Hierodula membranacea)', 'Praying mantis (Hierodula membranacea)',
                                     'proechimys', 'rabbit', 'Rana esculenta', 'Ranitomeya imitator', 'rat', 'Rhinella arenarum', 'Ruddy turnstone', 'salamander',
                                     'Scinax granulatus', 'Sea lamprey', 'Semipalmated plover', 'Semipalmated sandpiper', 'sheep', 'Silkmoth', 'spiny lobster', 'Stellers Sculpin',
                                     'Tiger', 'Toadfish', 'Treeshrew', 'turtle', 'Wallaby', 'Xenopus laevis', 'Xenopus tropicalis', 'Zebra', 'zebra finch', 'zebrafish', 'Not reported'], 
                           value=  'mouse', description='Animal:')
    display(widg2)
    
    widg3 = widget.Dropdown(options=['Glia', 'interneuron', 'principal cell', 'sensory', 'Not reported'], 
                            value=  'principal cell', description='Cell Type:')
    display(widg3)
    
    str1 = widg1.value
    str2 = widg2.value
    str3 = widg3.value
    query = (
        "http://neuromorpho.org/api/neuron/select?q=brain_region:%s&fq=species:%s&fq=cell_type:%s" % (str1, str2, str3))
    print(query)

response = requests.get(query)
json_data = response.json()
rat_data = json_data
rat_data

url = 'http://neuromorpho.org/api/neuron/select'
params = {
        'page' : 0,
        'q' : 'brain_region:' + widg1.value,
        'fq' : [
            'cell_type:' + widg3.value,
            'species:' + widg2.value,
            ]
        }

first_page_response = requests.get(url, params)

if first_page_response.status_code == 404 or first_page_response.status_code == 500:
  exit (1)

print (first_page_response.json())
totalPages = first_page_response.json()['page']['totalPages']


df_dict = {
        'NeuronID' : list(),
        'Neuron Name' : list(),
        'Archive' : list(),
        'Note' : list(),
        'Age Scale' : list(),
        'Gender' :  list(),
        'Age Classification' :  list(), 
        'Brain Region' :  list(),
        'Cell Type' : list(),
        'Species' :  list(),
        'Strain' :  list(),
        'Scientific Name' :  list(),
        'Stain' :  list(),
        'Experiment Condition' :  list(),
        'Protocol' :  list(),
        'Slicing Direction' :  list(),
        'Reconstruction Software' : list(),
        'Objective Type' :  list(),
        'Original Format' :  list(),
        'Domain' :  list(),
        'Attributes' :  list(),
        'Magnification' :  list(),
        'Upload Date' :  list(),
        'Deposition Date' :  list(),
        'Shrinkage Reported' :  list(),
        'Shrinkage Corrected' :  list(),
        'Reported Value' :  list(),
        'Reported XY' :  list(),
        'Reported Z' :  list(),
        'Corrected Value' :  list(),
        'Corrected XY' :  list(),
        'Corrected Z' :  list(),
        'Slicing Thickness' :  list(),
        'Min Age' :  list(),
        'Max Age' :  list(),
        'Min Weight' :  list(),
        'Max Weight' :  list(),
        'Png URL' :  list(),
        'Reference PMID' :  list(),
        'Reference DOI' :  list(),
        'Physical Integrity' :  list() }

for pageNum in range(totalPages):
    params['page'] = pageNum
    response = requests.get(url, params)
    print('Querying page {} -> status code: {}'.format(
        pageNum, response.status_code))
    if (response.status_code == 200):    #only parse successful requests
        data = response.json()
        for row in data['_embedded']['neuronResources']:
            df_dict['NeuronID'].append(str(row['neuron_id']))
            df_dict['Neuron Name'].append(str(row['neuron_name']))
            df_dict['Archive'].append(str(row['archive']))
            df_dict['Note'].append(str(row['note']))
            df_dict['Age Scale'].append(str(row['age_scale']))
            df_dict['Gender'].append(str(row['gender']))
            df_dict['Age Classification'].append(str(row['age_classification']))
            df_dict['Brain Region'].append(str(row['brain_region']))
            df_dict['Cell Type'].append(str(row['cell_type']))
            df_dict['Species'].append(str(row['species']))
            df_dict['Strain'].append(str(row['strain']))
            df_dict['Scientific Name'].append(str(row['scientific_name']))
            df_dict['Stain'].append(str(row['stain']))
            df_dict['Experiment Condition'].append(str(row['experiment_condition']))
            df_dict['Protocol'].append(str(row['protocol']))
            df_dict['Slicing Direction'].append(str(row['slicing_direction']))
            df_dict['Reconstruction Software'].append(str(row['reconstruction_software']))
            df_dict['Objective Type'].append(str(row['objective_type']))
            df_dict['Original Format'].append(str(row['original_format']))
            df_dict['Domain'].append(str(row['domain']))
            df_dict['Attributes'].append(str(row['attributes']))
            df_dict['Magnification'].append(str(row['magnification']))
            df_dict['Upload Date'].append(str(row['upload_date']))
            df_dict['Deposition Date'].append(str(row['deposition_date']))
            df_dict['Shrinkage Reported'].append(str(row['shrinkage_reported']))
            df_dict['Shrinkage Corrected'].append(str(row['shrinkage_corrected']))
            df_dict['Reported Value'].append(str(row['reported_value']))
            df_dict['Reported XY'].append(str(row['reported_xy']))
            df_dict['Reported Z'].append(str(row['reported_z']))
            df_dict['Corrected Value'].append(str(row['corrected_value']))
            df_dict['Corrected XY'].append(str(row['corrected_xy']))
            df_dict['Corrected Z'].append(str(row['corrected_z']))
            df_dict['Slicing Thickness'].append(str(row['slicing_thickness']))
            df_dict['Min Age'].append(str(row['min_age']))
            df_dict['Max Age'].append(str(row['max_age']))
            df_dict['Min Weight'].append(str(row['min_weight']))
            df_dict['Max Weight'].append(str(row['max_weight']))
            df_dict['Png URL'].append(str(row['png_url']))
            df_dict['Reference PMID'].append(str(row['reference_pmid']))
            df_dict['Reference DOI'].append(str(row['reference_doi']))
            df_dict['Physical Integrity'].append(str(row['physical_Integrity']))
           
neurons_df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

I know that this might be confusing to somebody not familiar to this, but i have placed some markdowns inside the notebook to explain in detail what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, not touching random links or downloads. Feel free to post the code in question as text. If it's too big to post here, trim it down until you have a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Ok but i have a problem with the entire notebook code. I have added first part of the code

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take a look on the [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) and [Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/). They can produce the standalone executables.
Example with `nuitka`:

```
(linux) python -m nuitka --onefile --output-dir=./nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --plugin-enable=qt-plugins ./../updater.py
(windows) python -m nuitka --onefile --windows-uac-admin --windows-disable-console --windows-icon-from-ico=.\updater\resources\ico\au.ico --output-dir=.\nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --plugin-enable=qt-plugins --windows-company-name=Name --windows-product-name=Name --windows-product-version=1.0.0 --windows-file-description=Name .\..\updater.py
```

Example with `pyinstaller`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=./updater/resources/ico/au.ico updater.py
```

Comment: Made an executable with PyInstaller as i said in my first post and it didn't work.